# Show name of program on the windows taskbar while not running?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have a vertical taskbar. The name of the program is shown alongside the program icon. (Right-click Taskbar -> Properties -> "Taskbar Buttons: Never Combine")

However, this is when the program is active **only**.

How can I show the name *also* when the program is inactive?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to set this, I've had a play about with the suggestion on this site: http://www.mydigitallife.info/never-combine-icons-or-only-combine-when-full-but-hide-labels-in-windows-7-taskbar/, however that only appears to affect labels on active programs.

I will continue to have a little bit of a Google and if I find anything, come back to you.

**UPDATE**

I've been having another look at this and found some more information for you, one thing is an update on the link above, the other is a workaround.

So the first part: http://www.thefreewindows.com/3693/change-the-size-width-of-taskbar-buttons-on-windows-7/

I will warn you that this requires some changes to the registry, so do so with caution and make sure you have a backup :)

Anyway, I suggest, try putting in the key that they suggest; MinValue (String Value) under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics 
Then make the value of the key something between 38 & 50.  This might help.  I would say the max you would want to give it is 500 really, that would take up a lot of space on your taskbar.

If that doesn't work, have a look at this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/53fcc34d-19e9-48aa-849e-5db820ab6154/is-there-a-way-to-always-show-labels-on-all-buttons-on-the-task-bar?forum=w7itproui

This won't give you labels on inactive programs, however there are some options you can use.  
One that I always use is to put the Desktop toolbar onto the Taskbar (right click the taskbar > hover over Toolbars > Click Desktop). 
This will give you a menu option on the right-hand side of the task bar, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AYVl.jpg

I know it's not an exact answer, however I think that this is the best option you have short of having to use third party software or making changes to the underlying system files / settings.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program, right click its button on the taskbar, and hit Pin to Taskbar.  See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Pin-a-program-to-the-taskbar) from MS.  (This seems too straightforward-am I missing something in your question?)

Comment: This does not show the name of the program when the program is not running.